# Why does alert("1" - - "1"); produce 2 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I execute the following javascript statement:

```
alert("1" - - "1");
```

I get the result 2.

Why is this?

Comment: `(1 - (-1))` == 2

Comment: I didn't expect Javascript to convert the type so easily. The math wasn't the issue.  But yeah.. got it.

Comment: I know some more seasoned devs are going to groan at this question but the OP clearly has an enquiring mind and a desire to understand how stuff works. I feel this is a good question for a beginner to be considering obvious though the answer is to the rest of us.

Comment: See the [*Unary - Operator*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-unary-minus-operator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you can't subtract strings, the `-` operator converts them to numbers. If you subtract negative one from positive one you get two.

Comment: Ah cool.. I knew Javascript was loosely typed.. I guess I didn't know, that loose. Thanks.